# N Circle touching x-axis and fixed point

Tags: limits, conic-sections

If a circle $C_0$, with radius $1$ unit touches both the axes and as well as line ($ L_1
$) through $P(0,4)$, $L_1$
cut the $x$-axis at $(x_1 ,0)$ . Again a circle $C_1$ is drawn touching $x$-axis, line $L_1$
and another line $L_2$
through point $P$. $L_2$
intersects $x$-axis at $(  x_2,0)$ and this process is repeated $n$ times. Then the value of : $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{x_n}{2^n} $$ is

I am only able to find $C_1$ which is $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and $L_1$ which is $3x+4y=12$ but not able to proceed forward

Comment: Each of the circles have radius 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let points $C_n=(c_n,1)$ be the centers of the circles and $X_{n}=(x_n,0)$ the intersections of tangent lines with $x$-axis (see figure). As $C_{n-1}X_nC_n$ is a right triangle (because
$C_{n-1}X_n$ and $X_nC_n$ are bisectors of adjacent angles), then by the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem)
the square of its altitude from $X_n$ (which has unit length) equals the product of the two parts into which the altitude divides the hypothenuse, that is:
$(x_n-c_{n-1})(c_n-x_n)=1$.
If we set $\delta_n=c_{n}-x_n$
this can be restated as
$x_n-c_{n-1}=1/\delta_n$ and we obtain:

$$
\tag{1}
c_{n}-c_{n-1}={1\over\delta_n}+\delta_n.
$$

On the other hand, if $T_n$ is the tangency point in figure below, we have
$PT_n=PX_n-\delta_n$ and (by the Pythagorean theorem) $PT_n^2=PC_{n}^2-1$, that is:

$$
\Big(\sqrt{(c_{n}-\delta_n)^2+16}-\delta_n\Big)^2=c_{n}^2+9-1,
$$
which gives:
$$
\tag{2}
c_{n}={2\over\delta_n}-\delta_n.
$$
Plugging this into $(1)$ gives then
$$
c_{n-1}={1\over\delta_n}-2\delta_n
\quad\text{and}\quad
{1\over\delta_{n+1}}-2\delta_{n+1}={2\over\delta_n}-\delta_n,
$$
that is:
$$
\delta_{n+1}={1\over2}\delta_n.
$$
As we can easily compute $\delta_1={1\over2}$ it follows that
$$
\delta_n={1\over2^n}
\quad\text{and}\quad
x_n=c_n-\delta_n={2\over\delta_n}-2\delta_n=2^{n+1}-{1\over2^{n-1}},
$$
whence $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n\over 2^n}=2$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir for proper explanation in the past also you have solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is a known configuration 
when $\triangle POX_n$ with the height $h=|OP|$ and inradius $r$
is split into $n$
triangles $\triangle POX_1,\triangle PX_1X_2,\dots\triangle PX_{n-1}X_n$,
such that all their incircles have the same radius $r_n$.

The radius $r$ of the inscribed circle of $\triangle POX_n$
is found as

\begin{align} 
r&=\frac h2\,\left(1- \left(1-\frac{2r_n}h \right)^n \right)
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}
For $h=4,r_n=1$ we have

\begin{align} 
r&=2-2^{1-n}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
2r&=|OP|+|OX_n|-|PX_n|
=h+x_n-\sqrt{h^2+x_n^2}
,\\ 
x_n&=
\frac{2r(h-r)}{h-2r}
=2^{n+1}-2^{1-n}
,\\
\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{x_n}{2^n}
&=\frac{2^{n+1}-2^{1-n}}{2^n}
=2
.
\end{align}